# Using the word "extrapolate"

Tags: grammar

I had no trouble understanding the sentence below. But, the second sentence doesn't seem to be grammatically correct. Can anyone explain how the second sentence is 'grammatically' wrong and how it should have been written?

Below is an excerpt from the script of a popular [video](http://www.cgpgrey.com/blog/humans-need-not-apply).

> The transportation industry in the United States employs about three million people. **Extrapolating world-wide that’s something like 70 million jobs at a minimum.**

Comment: Put a comma after "world-wide".

Comment: Is this question about the use of the word *extrapolate*, as indicated by its title, **or** about the grammatical structure of the quoted sentence, as indicated by the body of the question?

Comment: Why, Sarah? Given the context, what did you think was wrong?

Answer (score -2):

I think the second sentence has a dangling modifier. The second sentence starts with a participle phrase "Extrapolating world-wide" in which it doesn't modify anything.

There are two ways to fix this error.

1. First, identify the actor of the action word "extrapolate" and then make it as the subject. Sample is as follows:

Rather than this

"*Having* read your letter, **my cat** will stay indoors until the ducklings fly off."

it must be structured this way

"*Having* read your letter, **we** will keep our cat indoors until the ducklings fly off."

(The subject can be anyone identified as the actor of the participle 'having'.)

Note that it's not the cat that read the letter, but someone (in this sample, I used "we")

2. Rewrite the entire sentence or the introductory phrase to avoid a dangling modifier.

Sample:

- Running seriously for a competition, some fans blocked his way.

should be:

- Running seriously for a competition, Usain Bolt had his way blocked by some fans.

OR

- As Usain Bolt was running seriously for a competition, some fans blocked his way.

Comment: Of course, you need to take note that not all words that ends in -ing  and also starts a sentence as an introductory word/phrase follow the pattern above.